# What passenger airplane has the lowest fuel efficiency?

Tags: fuel, efficiency, fuel-consumption

What is the airplane with the lowest fuel efficiency? To set some parameters, let's limit it to the following:

- Must be manufactured between 1960 and modern day.
- Must be a non-military passenger airplane.
- Must use liquid fuel (100LL, Jet-A, etc.)
- Can be a commercial aircraft or GA airplane, but must be manned and have passenger seats. No helicopters!
- Spacecraft don't count! (You know you were thinking of this)
- Must be in the highest standard seat count configuration for the airplane. You cannot take a large jet like an A380, and remove all of the seats save for one!

**Fuel efficiency is calculated in pmpg (Passenger miles per gallon)**, which is the total miles per gallon of the aircraft, divided by the maximum number of seated passengers. This does not include pilot, copilot, or any associated crew as passengers.

**Please link back to credible sources, and show how you arrived at your pmpg in terms of mpg and passenger count.**

Comment: helicopters of course hell yeah. Like I said, if you mean airplane, say airplane.

Comment: @user3528438 Good catch - added that disclaimer!

Comment: Still, IMO, a bit too broad. The Cessna 172 (GA SEP aircraft) can also have 2-3 passengers. Maybe limit to turbine powered or some minimum weight / passengers count?

Comment: You might want to change it to "lowest *best* fuel efficiency". That'd fix many of the loopholes like helicopters and passenger count.

Comment: @Matt you might want to look at Concorde / Tu-144 or a business jet as the worst in terms of miles per gallon per passenger.

Comment: @ElectricPilot Concorde is about ~30pmpg, which is pretty bad, but there's got to be some worse aircraft out there. If we were talking strictly about mpg, and not pmpg, then it would be a serious contender. I haven't done the math on a Tu-144 but as an "aircraft of scale" (with lots of seats), it would likely have a similar outcome.

Comment: @Matt I've read few articles about early version of the Tu-144 and one of the retired pilots mentioned that it was consuming close to 40 tonnes per hour. Hard to believe, I know, but it looks to be not far from the truth. I would say that early Soviet Jet liners would be on top of the list of what are you looking for. Once I will gather some data, I will try to update my answer. Old piston and turboprop designs were still much more economical.

Comment: @ElectricPilot Did the math, Tu-144 turns out to be 9.8pmpg. It's the top contender right now, but I feel that there's likely something *even worse*!

Comment: Whichever one has to sit on the tarmac for hours with its engines turning but not going anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

**TU-144** =  9.78 passenger mpg

TU-144 figures found on another forum, from an official flight planning document:
https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1355819#p19483811

--

By comparison the **TU-104A** = 15.88 passenger mpg

From an old Aviation Week story on the TU-104:
http://aviationweek.com/blog/tupolev-104-harsh-proof-rapid-soviet-progress-1956

Using that article and assuming 0.8 l per kg and 20% reserve, imperial gallons. These figures (especially TU-104A) are rough and would vary by loading and flight profile.

Comment: I was immediately thinking of the Concorde but yes the Tu144 would probably be even worse :D

Answer (score 2):

In production: Depending on the configuration its likely to be some variant of the [Boeing Business Jet (BBJ)](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/bbj/) this is the blanket term for the companies line of custom built aircraft. Many of these are large aircraft built to cary, in some cases, one person. Their fuel to passenger ratio is pretty bad. Lets take take a look at [the biggest private Boeing BBJ, this 747-8](https://www.businessinsider.com/boeing-747-8-vip-private-jet-2016-6), which [burns 9.9 kg/km (35 lb/mi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_aircraft) or 5.1 Gallons Per Mile, lets say there are 30 people on board that puts at **5.88 PMPG** assuming the owner has a few friends.

Out of production: The [Concorde burned 5,638 gallons (38338.4 LBS) of fuel an hour](https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/about-ba/history-and-heritage/celebrating-concorde) and served [plenty of charter missions with light passenger loads](http://omegataupodcast.net/166-flying-the-concorde/). The Concorde cruised around Mach 2.02 at altitude that computes to ~1155 Kts which puts them right at 4.88 Gallons Per Nautical Mile, lets assume a light charter load of ~30 passengers (eluded to in the above linked podcast) that brings you **6.15 PMPG**

Comment: I would say a good contender in terms of worst fuel burn per mile / passenger would be a long range, high cruise speed business jet and Concorde with Tu-144.

Comment: Saudi Prince Alwaleed bin Talal al-Saud [has his own Airbus A380](http://www.abi.gr/5-most-expensive-private-jets/) while probably not carrying a single person, would probably be worse than the BBJ's.

Comment: @RonBeyer I had found that article but after some more digging it [appears the plane never really came to be.](https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/business-aviation/2015-02-05/airbus-cancels-only-vvip-a380-order)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question regarding pmpg.

Comment: @Matt: It's ridiculously unlikely you can beat the Concorde without stretching the definitions pretty hard.

Comment: @Joshua I wasn't saying that - I was saying that his answer does not answer within the confines of my question. Plus, the Concorde burned 5,638gph, and traveled 1,354mph, which gives you ~0.24mpg, and with it's passenger configuration of 128 passengers, that's ~30pmpg, far from being the "most inefficient" aircraft, particularly when you take into account ~60's era GA airplanes. If you say "served light loads", then literally any plane would be inefficient when it's doing an empty flight. It's a non-answer.

Comment: The question asks for aircraft in maximum passenger capacity configuraton -- so for, say, a Cessna 182, that would be four passengers (plus pilot and copilot).

Comment: @ZeissIkon Partially correct - pmpg (which is what's used in industry) does not include crew seats, so you would multiple that mpg by two in order to get the pmpg of a Cessna 182, as it only carries two "passengers".

Comment: This answer does meet the requirements of the question.

Comment: @Matt I always get confused on that -- 152 is 2 seats, 172 is four, 182 must just carry more luggage or fly faster.  Six seats must be the 210 family.

Comment: @JuanJimenez No it doesn't - the question *specifically* asks for pmpg, and that is not referenced anywhere in this question. Nor do his suggestions follow the criteria laid out.

Comment: @JuanJimenez sorry for the delay I was out all day and was intending on adding to this I have updated it with numbers.